# Pandas df return indices of duplicated elements as a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to have the indexes of duplicated column elements as a list. So far, the way I found is

```
test = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
testdf = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['test'])
np.asarray(np.where(list(testdf['test'].duplicated()))).tolist()[0]
# [1, 4]
```

Which seems ridiculously convoluted.

Any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.duplicated()` with `.tolist()`

```
testdf.index[testdf.test.duplicated()].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this just indexing the index:

```
testdf.index[testdf['test'].duplicated()]
```

add `to_list`:

```
testdf.index[testdf['test'].duplicated()].to_list()
```

Output:

```
[1, 4]
```

Comment: sorry but that gives `Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')`, how can I get a list from that?

Comment: Add `.to_list()`

Answer (score 0):

```
%%time

test = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
testdf = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['test'])
testdf[testdf.test.duplicated()].index.to_list()

# Wall time: 2 ms
# [1, 4]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.